# What is the fastest way to put the first axis behind the last one? [numpy]

Tags: python, numpy

Let us look at this stupid example with a N0 x N1 x ... x Nm dimensional array, such as

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random([N0,N1,...,Nm])
```

Now I want the N0 dimension to be behind the last one, i.e.

```
np.swapaxis np.swapaxis(np.swapaxis(x, 0,1),1,2) ... # swapping m times
```

I tried with np.rollaxis, but this seems to be the wrong function. In the end, I want to have an array with shape (N1,N2,N3,...,Nm,N0).

Any nice ideas?

Comment: try `arr.transpose(range(1, Nm)+[0])`

Comment: "I tried with np.rollaxis, but this seems to be the wrong function." - how did you come to the conclusion that it's the wrong function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried with np.rollaxis, but this seems to be the wrong function.

No, it's the right function.

```
x = numpy.rollaxis(x, 0, x.ndim)
```